# How to create space between x-axis labels in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library.

I'm trying to make spaces between labels in the XAxis of my line chart.

I have tried this but nothing changes:

```
xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(someInt);
```

Comment: Try yourBarDataSet.setBarSpacePercent(30f);

Comment: Im using LineDataSet

Comment: try chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5); that reduces the maximum amount of values that can be shown at once. As far as i know there is no method that creates space between x-axis labels for line chart.

Comment: That will work, thank you very much.

Comment: if it works, i'm gonna write it as an answer that might be found easier than a comment.

Comment: It works for me because I want the graph to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Problem is now that I want to show the last 5 X values first.

Comment: chart.moveViewTo(yourNumberOfXPoints); or chart.moveViewToX(yourNumberOfXPoints);

Comment: perfect, thank you. I posted another question for it if you want to answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737521/how-can-mpandroidchart-begin-at-the-last-xvalues-with-a-large-dataset/39739865#39739865

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you can increase the zoom level using zoom(scaleX, scaleY, x, y) method. Increase the scaleX value and you will start seeing spaces between labels on the x axis. A good estimation is dividing the number of labels by 10. So if you have 500 labels, use zoom(50f, 0.5f, 1f, 1f).

Answer (score 0):

```
    xAxis.labelCount = 3
```

//replace the integer with whatever you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xAxis.setLabelCount(some int);`

or

```
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(some float);
```

which sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be minimum visible at once.

You can read it also in the documentation
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis

and for the View Port https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport