# How can MPAndroidChart begin at the last x-value with a large dataset?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library in Android.

I'm trying to get the graph to start at the last set of x values.

I would like to show every day of the year up until now so 1 - 271 (today is the 271st day of the year)

I am using

```
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10)
```

but the chart begins by showing day 1 - 10 and I want to start by showing day 261 - 271.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MPAndroidChart's wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport), try

`chart.moveViewToX(yourNumberOfXPoints);` or `chart.moveViewTo(yourNumberOfXPoints);`

Why?

> moveViewToX(float xValue): Moves the left side (edge) of the current
>   viewport to the specified x-value.
>
> moveViewTo(float xValue, float yValue, AxisDependency axis): This will
>   move the left side of the current viewport to the specified x-value on
>   the x-axis, and center the viewport to the specified y-value on the
>   provided y-axis (makes sense in combination with setVisibleXRange(...)
>   and setVisibleYRange(...).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to use  `IAxisValueFormatter`

```
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

private String[] mValues;

public MyXAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
    this.mValues = values;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    // "value" represents the position of the label on the axis (x or y)
    return mValues[(int) value];
}

/** this is only needed if numbers are returned, else return 0 */
@Override
public int getDecimalDigits() { return 0; }}
```

In this `mValues` is an array which contains values which you want to set in xAxis. in your case array contains  261 - 271 values.

For more details please see : [this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface)

Comment: I don't see how that can start from the end but                  chart.moveViewToX(yourNumberOfXPoints); works